# How can I achieve "page specific js" and "less http requests" both on same webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have added so many js files in my project which helps to make it page specific but I also want to reduce http requests (which now calling so many http requests for each js file causes website performance).

Comment: Are you sure that you need so many Javascript files?  You may be simply splitting your code too much.

Comment: You should merge them to one file and compress it.

Comment: If I combine all js files, unwanted code of scripts will get called/load even if I don't require it on that page which will cause the page loading time

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to this. Three that immediately come to mind are:

- Have your code in a single minified file and have an inline script after it calling the appropriate initialization function(s) for that specific page. So for instance, on `page1.js`:

  ```
  <script src="allthecode.js"></script>
  <script>MyApp.page1Init();</script>
  ```
- Have your code in one minified file and have the code sniff the page URL via the `location` object, and dispatch to the appropriate initialization function(s).
- Have all of your common code in one minified file, and have one minified file per page with only the page-specific code. So for instance:

  ```
  <script src="allthecode.js"></script>
  <script src="page1.js"></script>
  ```

Note that keeping your code in separate files for development is usually a good thing; but then you can use a build step with any of the many build tools / task runners out there (Gulp, Grunt, Webpack, ...) to combine and minify your code into one or two files for production use.